# Search through whole line and change words with ize to ise using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to search all the words in a line/sentence and detect any word with ize and convert it to ise except for certain words listed.

Find: `^(?!size)(?!resize)(?!Belize)(?!Bizet)(?!Brize)(?!Pfizer)(?!assize)(?!baize)(?!bedizen)(?!citizen)(?!denizen)(?!filesize)(?!maize)(?!prize)(?!netizen)(?!seize)(?!wizen)(?!outsize)(?!oversize)(?!misprize)(?!supersize)(?!undersize)(?!unsized)(?!upsize)([a-zA-Z-\s]+)ize`

Replace: `$1ise`

So far all i get is the first word of the line with ize to work, or the last word with ize to work.

Example Organize to socialize whatever size.
To Organise to socialise whatever size.

```
Find (?i)(?!size|resize|Belize|so&so|unsized|upsize)(?<!\w)(\w+)ize

Replace $1ise
```

worked as intended. Capitalisation issues added (?i)

Comment: Could you please extend your example to a before/after case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `([a-zA-Z-\s]+)ize` has the whitespace marker in it (`\s`) so it will will match anything beyond the word boundary. You might want to work with `\w` and/or `\b` to match only characters from the word where the "ize" is located. Additionally, you don't want the `^` at the beginning since this would match the start of the string.

Possible regex: `(?!....your list....)(\w+)ize`

Example input: "Organize to socialize whatever size."

Found matches: "Organize" and "socialize", but not "size", see https://regex101.com/r/UIfoa8/1

After that you can use your replacement `$1ise` to replace the found string with the captured group and "ise".

Comment: Thanks for the help, so close. I managed to get it. (?<!\w) was needed.

Answer (score 0):

## Make a Whitelist Array

- Make the excluded words (`whitelist`) an array of strings
- [`.split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text being searched through (`searchStr`) into an array
- then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through each word of the array

  - using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to compare a word vs. the `whitelist`
  - using [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to see if it's a `x+"ize"` word to [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- Once the `searchArray` is complete, [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it into a string (`resultString`).

---

### Demo

**"organize", "mesmerized", "socialize", and "baptize" was mixed into the search string of some whitelist words**

```js
var searchStr = `organize Belize Bizet mesmerized Brize Pfizer assize baize bedizen citizen denizen filesize socialize maize prize netizen seize wizen outsize baptize`;

var whitelist = ["size", "resize", "Belize", "Bizet", "Brize", "Pfizer", "assize", "baize", "bedizen", "citizen", "denizen", "filesize", "maize", "prize", "netizen", "seize", "wizen", "outsize", "oversize", "misprize", "supersize", "undersize", "unsized", "upsize"];

var searchArray = searchStr.split(' ').map(function(word) {
  var match;
  if (whitelist.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
    match = word;
  } else if (/([a-z]+?)ize/i.test(word)) {
    match = word.replace(/([a-z]+?)ize/i, '$1ise');
  } else {
    match = word;
  }
  return match;
});

var resultString = searchArray.join(', ');

console.log(resultString);
```